# SQL Server inserting Date as 1/1/1900

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am having ASP Classic page to insert record in table. 
I am using form element for 5 fields viz.  [ABC] ([code], [updatedate], [flag], [Mfdate]. And using the date control to get user selected date in Mdate when user does not select the Mdate, the query that it is getting formed in my ASP page is as below

```
INSERT INTO [ABC] ([code], [updatedate], [flag], [Mfdate]) 
VALUES('203 ', '6/12/2013', 'N/A', '')
```

When it is run in SQL Server it is inserting date `1/1/1900` for `Mfdate` but User has not selected any value.

Why is it happening like this?

The  data type for `Mfdate` is `datetime`.

Comment: The value '' is being passed in for Mfdate. Thats not the same as NULL.

Comment: Is there a trigger on that table?

Comment: Also, is it "1990" or "1900"?

Comment: @StingyJack `SELECT CAST(''  as datetime)` = `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`

Comment: @MartinSmith - yeah, but the OP says "1990"

Comment: True. It is surely wrong.

Comment: Agreed, but like @RBarryYoung says, it could be a trigger setting the 1990 value.

Comment: Sorry Its 1900 and not 1990 ..my mistake..there is no trigger on the Table...

Comment: It's not a trigger. SQL Server treats 1900/01/01 as a magic number. Bad dog!

Comment: `SELECT CASE WHEN {D'1900-01-01'} = '' THEN 'BAD DOG' ELSE 'GOOD DOG' END, CASE WHEN {D'1900-01-02'} = '' THEN 'BAD DOG' ELSE 'GOOD DOG' END`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have not given it as null, you're trying to insert an empty string (`''`).  You need:

```
INSERT INTO [ABC] ([code],[updatedate],[flag],[Mfdate]) 
VALUES ('203', '6/12/2013','N/A', NULL)
```

Although really, if you're going to be inserting dates, best to insert them in YYYYMMDD format, as:

```
INSERT INTO [ABC] ([code],[updatedate],[flag],[Mfdate]) 
VALUES ('203', '20130612','N/A', NULL)
```

Comment: Why do you say "best"?  I would think one of the ISO formats would be better as they arent confused by culture differences.

Comment: @StingyJack -- according to [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), YYYY-MM-DD is the accepted date format as I've suggested.  But Aaron Bertrand could show up at any minute to say that I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, Aaron insists that `'YYYYMMDD'` should be used as there are (rare) settings where even the YYYY-MM-DD will fail in SQL-Server: **[Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)**

Comment: @ypercube - thanks for that; I've edited my answer.  And I even found [Aaron's tweet](https://twitter.com/AaronBertrand/statuses/332578398000005120) on the subject.  I just need to bash that into my head now...

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Changing to NULL is working fine..but I am reading this data from Form input element which is of type text and when the date is not selected it is forming this insert query dynamically and causing the issue mentioned...any suggestion on this?

Comment: @Codelearner - you really need to edit your question with your code, since I have no idea if you're using C#, VB.NET, Java, PHP, Perl or something else.  It basically boils down to checking for the empty string, and passing in the appropriate equivalent of NULL to the parameter.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables check now

Comment: @Codelearner - I don't see any code.  How exactly are you building the SQL string?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I followed the approach( It basically boils down to checking for the empty string, and passing in the appropriate equivalent of NULL to the parameter.) you suggested and got the code working.

Answer (score 12):

The epoch, or zero point, of SQL Server's calendar is 1 January 1900 at start-of-day (00:00:00.000).

The internal representation of a `datetime` consists of 2 32-bit signed integers. The high-order integer is the county of days since the epoch; the low-order integer is the count of milliseconds since start-of-day. Anything that results in the `datetime` value's representation being zero, such as:

```
select convert(datetime,0)
select convert(datetime,'')
select convert(datetime,0x0000000000000000)
```

will yield the epochal `datetime` value of `1 January 1900 00:00:00.000`.

A `null`, however, is converted to … well … `null`, as the SQL standard requires that any expression or test involving a `null` (excepting the explicit test for nullity using `is [not] null` must itself evaluate to `null`.

OTOH, if you have SQL Server's options set up to treat `null` and nil strings pretty much interchangeably, you might well wind up with the epoch date.