# Why does 1/1/1900 get inserted into SQL? Is it an alternative to NULL in some cases?

Tags: c#, sql

I've got an API that is passed a string that this particular system treats as NULL "1/1/1900".  I've seen [other users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070859/sql-server-inserting-date-as-1-1-1900) with a similar value inserted where null is expected in SQL.  I tried this wacky setup:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var input = "01/1/1900";//this does NOT evaluate to DBNull
    var result = IsBasicallyNull(input);
}

private static bool IsBasicallyNull(string input)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        return true;
    if (DBNull.Value.Equals(input))//THis doesn't work
        return true;

    //hack and slash
    DateTime output;
    var isValidDateTime = DateTime.TryParse(input, out output);

    if (isValidDateTime)
    {
        if (output == DateTime.MinValue)
            return true;
        else if (output.Year.ToString() == "1900" && output.Day.ToString() == "1" && output.Month.ToString() == "1")
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It's clear that `DBNull.Value` is not built to support this `"1/1/1900"` (MM/DD/YYY) oddity.  Is it abnormal to get this value in SQL and it be treated as `NULL`?  Do you know where this value comes from?

Comment: I would use `IsNullOrEmpty` personally for this first check `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` also do a google search on `DBNull.Value` this is an Object and you are trying to compare the value of a string to an actual object.value

Comment: Why would you expect any date to be equal to `DBNull`?

Comment: @ZoranHorvat Well, string representation of date, but yes.

Comment: `DBNull.Value` is never ever equal to *anything* other than `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what database treats such date  string as null?

Comment: @Servy Yes, you're right about string. Even `null` string is not equal to `DBNull.Value`. It must be the `null` coming out from the database, which is again a non-null object which represents database null, to be equal to `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: @Evk I doubt it's the DB provider, more likely it's just a convention of a particular application that that date is used when a date is unknown, or perhaps some framework or platform built on top of the database.

Comment: @mcNets No, that's not the default value of a `DateTime` in C#.  That would be January 1, 0001.

Comment: @Servy yes, you're right

Comment: SQL Server will convert an empty string to 1900-01-01 if casted to a DateTime, that could be the source of this (select convert(datetime,'')). The OP may be thinking its null since they don't have the table in front of them, but the table itself may be holding dates as strings (OH BOY) which could cause this problem.

Comment: When you debug this, what it the value of `isValidDateTime` and `output`? Slightly OT: Why are you doing a ToString() instead of comparing `output.Year` to the integer value `1900`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a simllar problem in the past. Some columns of type smalldatetime with no null values accepted were filled with the [Minumum Value of a smalldatetime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182418.aspx) field. And this happen to be exactly 1/1/1900.

To consider these columns as they were null values I forced a piece of code like yours in this way

```
private static readonly DateTime minDB_smallDateTime = new DateTime(1900,1,1);

private static bool IsBasicallyNull(string input)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        return true;

    DateTime output;
    var isValidDateTime = DateTime.TryParse(input, out output);

    if (isValidDateTime && output <= minDB_smallDateTime)
       return true;

    .... rest of checking code....
}
```

Comment: Glad to see I'm not the only one that ran into this!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check wheter `input` is the string representation of a special date, you never can compare to `DBNull.Value` because it is something completely different. Try to compare against `new DateTime( 1900, 1, 1 ).ToString()` instead of.

Comment: But without the .ToString(). Else you will trip over `01` versus `1`