# Why does converting a blank string to a date in SQL Server result in 1900-01-01?

Tags: sql-server

Running a simple T-SQL query of `SELECT CONVERT(date, '')` will render a result of `1900-01-01`. It seems to me that it would be more consistent to convert a blank string to either `1753-01-01` (the minimum allowable date value) or `NULL`. 1900 just seems so arbitrary, but I assume this was a deliberate design choice made by the MS SQL programmers. What is the purpose of this functionality?

Comment: Try `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 0)` -- same result. The starting era of `DATETIME` is 1900-01-01 and earlier dates are represented with negative values. Excel uses the same; I'm sure there are other places (OLE DB/COM, I think?) where it's that value as well. As a nice round number, it's an obviously convenient starting point for dealing with two-digit years (in the 20th century when the software was written, that is). `DATETIME2` starts at 0001-01-01, though (but you can't directly convert integers to that, so it's not visible).

Answer (score 3):

It is due to implicit conversion. The 0 date in sql server is 1/1/1900. Any dates earlier than that are a negative number.

Comment: No, it does not convert the string to an int first -- `CONVERT(DATETIME, '1')` fails, `CONVERT(DATETIME, 1)` does not (same, to get tricky, with `'0'` and `0`). The empty string does also convert to `0`, but one is not a consequence of the other.

Comment: @JeroenMostert good point of clarification.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server datetime calendar start point is start of day of 01 January 1900.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17071583/7974050