# SQL table taking 1900-01-01 as a date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a date time option and I am trying to enter it in a sql table when the value is empty or blank it enters the table as 1900-01-01. Is there a way to create a sql statement to make this value NULL instead of 0?

```
UPDATE animals_table
 SET
   animalname = 'Mary'
   animaltype = 'Husky'
 WHERE
   animalid = '123456'
```

I was reading about case statements earlier I don't know if that is the correct direction to go about it, if it is this is where I started.

```
UPDATE animals_table
 SET
   animalname = 'Mary'
   animaltype = 'Husky'
 WHERE
   animalid = '123456'
 AND CASE
 WHEN
   dategiven = '1900-01-01'
 THEN
   dategiven = NULL;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server inserting Date as 1/1/1900](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070859/sql-server-inserting-date-as-1-1-1900)

Comment: which sql-server version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one `NULLIF` SQL2008+

```
UPDATE animals_table
 SET
   animalname = 'Mary'
   ,animaltype = 'Husky'
 WHERE
   animalid = '123456'
 and  ISNULL(NULLIF(dategiven,'1900-01-01'),'') = ''
```

or

```
 UPDATE animals_table
 SET
   animalname = 'Mary'
   ,animaltype = 'Husky'
 WHERE
   animalid = '123456'
 and  NULLIF(dategiven,'1900-01-01') IS NULL
```